# Where to find 3.5mm (male) to 3.5mm (male) cable that can control iPhone/iPod volume

Tags: iphone, ipod, headphones

Bonus if it has a mic and can handle iPhone calls

Basically I have a snowboarding helmet that has speakers built into it and has a 3.5mm (female) connection to the speakers.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Did you come up with your own solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about hardware shopping.

Answer (score 1):

There are such on ebay.com, I saw one today searching for "4 conductor 3.5mm [extension] cable" - I agree, they are rare. (You might have to build it yourself by buying two iPod earphones and then soldering the four cables, but I hope that's not necessary!)

Comment: The OP would want a cable with four conductors (TRRS) in one end and three (TRS) on the other. The helmet doesn't itself have volume controls or a mic.

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for it, but it looks like what you're asking for :-)

[http://www.amazon.com/3-5mm-Stereo-built-microphone-iPhone/dp/B003QNIBBS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003QNIBBS)

Comment: This indeed looks right.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd also want to skip the cable itself, I would suggest taking a look at the Jabra BT3030 Bluetooth "Headset", which you could connect with any male-to-male cable.